# Proving bounds for a function

Tags: asymptotics

I'm kinda confused by Asymptotics, the exercises in the book I'm reading say to prove for example $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$, and there is something I don't understand about these kind of proofs.
Do I have to prove them algebraically or is it possible to find some constant ($c$) such that this statement holds?

For example would it be correct to write $(n + a)^b = \Omega(n^b)$ since $ (n + a)^b \gg 1 \cdot n^b$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition it's enough to show existence of $c>0$, and, also existence of $N \in \mathbb{N}$, for which $f(n) \geqslant c g(n)$, when $n \gt N$. Of course, if it's possible to find $c$, then proof is also done.

In case of $(n + a)^b = \Omega(n^b)$, assuming $a,b>0$, then choice $c=N=1$ fulfills definition, as we have $(n + a)^b \geqslant  n^b$.

BTW, holds also $(n + a)^b = O(n^b)$, so $(n + a)^b = \Theta(n^b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)